# Making grid from a CSV file in R

Tags: r, interpolation, gstat

I am trying to make a grid file in R for the sake of krigging but when I try to use the code below an error shown below occurs.
My xy location data is in metric (UTM) and has 407x475 dimension with 1000 cell size and origin is at (93047,929543).

Code used:

```
data.grid <- read.csv("newgrid.csv",TRUE,",")
coordinates(data.grid) = ~X+Y
class(data.grid)
gridded(data.grid) = TRUE
```

Error displayed:

```
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.00035 
Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : 
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant
```

I am beginner in R and krigging.

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to guess without having the csv (is it available somewhere?). However, from the error I would say that the coordinates are not well constructed. Is the interval of coordinates always equal in the csv?

I'm sure there are more optimal ways to do this, but you can use the following code to check if all intervals are regular:

```
subsX <- vector()
subsY <- vector()

for (i in nrow(X)){
  if (i > 1){
    subsX[i-1] <- X$x[i] - X$x[i-1]
    subsY[i-1] <- X$y[i] - X$y[i-1]
  }
}

print(c(unique(subsX), unique(subsY)))
```

I hope it'd help.